# How to control peripheral power supply from microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, peripheral

I need to be able to control the 5Vdc power supply for a DS18b20 sensor and a 0.96 oled display from a microcontroller that works at 3v3.

I implemented this circuit, it correctly energizes the peripherals but I cannot turn them off correctly, since the output voltage in the off state is around 1.3V
[image]

I tried decreasing the value of the resistors with similar results.
[image]
What can I do to make the output voltage lower, around 500mV would be fine.

Edited:

This is the complete diagram after I remove the power control for the display and I will only control the power of the DS18b20 sensor, which is what I need most.
[image]

Comment: There are other leakage paths which you do not show. For example, if you have I2C pull-up resistors that are left powered, they can supply the unpowered components via data and clock pins and sometimes back-feeding power can even damage chips. So there is more to it than simply disconnecting supply voltage. Please show full schematics of the problematic circuit, not just the part where you think the problem is.

Comment: Good to see you removed R111.  You almost certainly can remove R112 also.  I agree with J - input pin transient protection circuits can provide a sneak path from a high input voltage to the internal Vcc or Vdd, especially if the external Vcc/Vdd source has gone to an off-state high impedance.

Comment: Agreed - to power the OLED down properly you’ll need to drive any micro pins low if they connect to it.  Setting the pins to be inputs may be ok if pull-ups are disabled but low outputs is preferable.

Comment: @Justme Very good point that I had not taken into account, now I will upload the complete diagram with these changes.

Comment: I also removed R111 as recommended by @AnalogKid

Comment: I was able to test the final circuit already and it works fine. Thanks a lot